# iOS 8 Core Data : open a sqllite UIManagedDocument never complete

Tags: core-data, ios8, ios8-today-widget

I am currently implementing an app using UIManagedDocument backed by a SQLLite database.
All was fine until I decided to implement a Today Extension.
This extension shares the same code of the main app to access the managed document.

The issue is when the extension has been used (inserted in the Notification Center and displayed) and then when the main app is "cold" started, the handler of "openWithCompletionHandler:" is never called.
The main controller of my app is declared as an observer of the UIManagedDocument and waiting for ever for the UIDocumentStateNormal state to occur to enable the user to do something.
If I put the an in background, display the notification center (with the extension), put the app in foreground again, then the document state changes to Normal and then the app works correctly.

But if I am too long to use app, the app is again "cold" started, then the same issue arises.

I am searching here and the Internet for weeks and did not find any clue. I've tried to avoid updates in the Extension but this changes nothing. I have tried to force reset the MOCs after each transaction (so that when the Extension is accessing the document, the MOCs should be clear and no update pending), but this changes nothing.

If someone could help...

Thanks a lot.

Philippe.